# Django's equivalent to Rails 5 min blog demo

Tags: python, django, blogs

Some how some way I'm trying to get out of Ruby because things are just working and I don't necessarily know why. I'm taking the forest for the trees approach by which I mean I'm trying to get perspective by learning a new language; Python/Django seems to be the right way to go.

The first application I built in Rails was from the 5 min blog screencast by DHH and form there I was able to get by. I'm looking for a relevant resource for learning a Django application in particular I"m looking for a simple blog application.

Comment: Did you go to the Django site?  Did you look at the Django tutorial?  If not, why not?

Comment: +1: Admitting you did nothing.  -1: Doing nothing.

Comment: @S.Lott ::heads over to Meta to request being able to up and downvote a question simultaneously::

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little bit of google-fu I turned up this relatively recent example:

- [Django Tutorial: A Simple Blog, Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20141223032833/http://lightbird.net/dbe/blog.html)
- [Django Tutorial: A Simple Blog, Part 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20141223032833/http://lightbird.net/dbe/blog2.html)

Comment: For what it's worth, the official Django tutorial is actually quite good as well and would be what I would recommend for everyone new to Django.  So maybe if you run into issues with this one, try the official tutorial.  Or if you finish this and want to learn some more, do the official one.  It has a lot more information in it.

Comment: Site no longer works. copy from archive.org  https://web.archive.org/web/20141223032833/http://lightbird.net/dbe/blog.html  https://web.archive.org/web/20141222015841/http://www.lightbird.net/dbe/blog2.html

Answer (score 2):

I would check out the official "writing your first..." tutorial on djangoproject.com: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

It's great and gets you started in no time.

Answer (score 2):

The Django site provides [a tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) on how to build a poll, which can be easily modified to build a blog.  James Bennett's book, [Practical Django Projects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219386), also explains in significant detail how to build a blog/cms.

Comment: thanks, i am looking for bare bones blog for the purpose of getting to know the framework by actually writing some code.